# multiple argument list with NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION

Tags: objective-c, xcode, list, variadic-functions, arguments

I have a function
-(id) func: params1, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION and2: params2, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION;

Compiler says: error: expected `;' before 'and2'
Is there any way to make function with 2 argument lists?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply put: No. It is not possible.

There is, however, a workaround available; you can pass instead two pointers to `id` that work out to nil-terminated arrays, like so:

```
- (id)method:(id *)part_one withTwo:(id *)part_two
```

**Edit:** As an alternative, the list could be `nil`-terminated *twice*. (Now that is weird!)

Comment: Not at all weird; you see it with NSDictionary, IIRC; `- (id)initWithObjects:(id *)objects forKeys:(id *)keys count:(NSUInteger)count` (It's a similar concept, but with the count thrown in as an optimization.)

Comment: touché; to my own defense, I almost *never* use that initializer on `NSDictionary`. ;)